Using APIKEY but getting "Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing."
I just want to use HERE maps with the simplest of all calls to retrieve the long/lat from a given location just like
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Berlin&apiKey=mykey

The response is always
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing."
}

It seems the system does not even try to use the APIKEY, instead it expects a bearer token. The docs are not quite clear about how to use the params, but their example looks like this.
What is the trick?
